# I have recently updated Ubuntu 22.10 to 23.04 and startup problem has arised

Tags: boot, updates, 23.04

I have recently updated the ubuntu verion to latest which is 23.04, everything was successfully but when i restarted ubuntu after update since then its not booting up the new version.

```
  20/psobject-220) [

0.255381] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCIO.P EGO.PEGP. OFF), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dswload2-326)

0.255390] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202210

20/psobject-220)

[ 0.255400] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [_SB.PCIO.P

EGO.PEGP.SGPO), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dswload2-326) [ 0.255409] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202210

20/psobject-220)

L 0.997328] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65 /dev/sda6: clean, 270228/6111232 files, 6703214/24413952 blocks [ 34.527532]

[242.754349] INFO: task systemd-udevd: 407 blocked for more than 120 seconds. [242.754417] Tainted: P

0 6.2.0-20-generic #20-Ubuntu

242.754460] "echo > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message [242.755401] INFO: task plymouthd:449 blocked for more than 120 seconds.

[

.

[242.755444] Tainted: P 0 6.2.0-20-generic #20-Ubuntu [242.755484] "echo > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

So what i did: I went to advanced ubuntu option and selected the second version() other than recovery mode and ubuntu is starting and then i checked the version by going to the setting and it say that i have ubuntu 23.04 installed.

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.6-20-generic 

Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-20-generic (recovery mode) 

* Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-42-generic

Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-42-generic (recovery mode)
```

But i am not sure what is the issue here, is it partially installed??
how can fix it?
Should i reinstall the whole thing after taking a backup (do not preferred this).